# OPL constraint index

Tags: constraints, cplex, opl

I am programming an OPL model and do not know how to express the following constraint:

```
q_t-D_t_T*v_t <=0
```

Where `D_t_T` is the sum of all `q_t` in the set of `t` to `T`.

-- Update --

Yes, just q[t] and v[t] are variables. Is the suggestion also working if I defined the range of `t` as follows:

```
//parameters
int T=...;                          
range Perioden=1..T;
```

My constraint looks then:

```
forall(t in Perioden)
  constraint1:
    q[t]- (sum(i in t..T) q[i])*v[t]<=0;
```

Maybe one more basic question: How do I express the [t-1] in the following expression:

```
forall(t in Perioden)
  constraint2:
    y[t-1]+q[t]-y[t]==q[t];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just `q[t]` and `v[t]` are variables.
Is your suggestion also working if I defined the range of t as follows:

```
//parameters
int T=...;                          
range Perioden=1..T;
```

My constraint looks then:

```
forall(t in Perioden)
  constraint1:
    q[t]- (sum(i in t..T) q[i])*v[t]<=0;
```

---

Maybe one more basic question:
How do I express the [t-1] in the following expression:

```
forall(t in Perioden)
  constraint2:
    y[t-1]+q[t]-y[t]==q[t];
```